# What does the notation $\pi$ mean in probability and statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

I have noticed that in the presentation of probability distribution, sometimes a certain probability is dentoed by $\pi(...)$. For example, in the wike page of Beta binomial distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution, they use $P(X=k|p,n)$ to denote the distribution of $X$, while using $\pi(p|\alpha,\beta) = Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ to denote the distribution of $p$. May I ask why the notation $\pi$ is used here? Is there a specific meaning?

Comment: Here it is used for density function of variable p given $\alpha, \beta$

Comment: $P(X=k|p,n)$ is also the density function, why they use $\pi()$ to denote the density function of $p$

Comment: $P$ is the probability mass function. $\pi$ notaion is usually used for continuous variable.

Comment: (1) n hypothesis-testing, $\pi$ is sometimes designates power [1 - P(Type II Error)];  (2) In Bayesian stat $\pi$ is used by some authors to designate a prior or posterior dist'n (3) In connection with binomial dist'ns $\pi$ is can be used instead of $p$ to denote Success probability, especially when authors want to use Greek letters for parameters. (4) If $\pi$ is used for a quantity other than 3.14159..., it is customary to make a comment to avoid confusion. The alternate form of  'pi' ($\varpi$) is not often used in stat or math, perhaps to avoid confusion with $\omega.$ or $\bar\omega.$

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it is bayesian stat I am talking about. So, $\pi$ can be used to designate prior or posterior distribution, and does not necessary need to be conjugate?

Answer (score 1):

ISLR (An Introduction to Statistical Learning) states:

> Let $π_k$ represent the overall or prior probability that a randomly
> chosen observation comes from the kth class.

This above is in reference to the the Bayes Theorem.

Bayes theorem is given by
$Pr(Y = k|X = x) = \frac{π_kf_k(x)}{\sum_{l=1}^{K}π_lf_l(x)}$

Note that the meaning of $f_k(x)$ as the following:

> Let $f_k(x) ≡ Pr(X = x|Y = k)$ denote the density function of X for an
> observation that comes from the kth class.

see page 138 and 139 (corresponds to the 152nd and 153rd page due to index etc.) in this link
https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf